# ExtJs - How to escape special characters in POST and GET XML data?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Following are the special characters I am dealing with:

```
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
"   &quot;
'   &apos;    
&   &amp;
```

When I am trying to POST xml content(contains <,>) like:

```
<id>123<abc</id>
```

Such user input is causing issues. I am not able to find a way to handle such data. Can someone guide me that how I can encode such data? 
For decode I am gonna change the data in Model. 
What's the best way to encode and decode such data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ext provides the method [`htmlEncode`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.String-method-htmlEncode) on the string utility class for this.

```js
var encoded = Ext.String.htmlEncode('< > & \' "'); 
console.log(encoded); // "&lt; &gt; &amp; &#39; &quot;"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. I used encodeURIComponent method to send data and in model i used decodeURIComponent method. And used method suggested by you as column renderer method and it worked.